# Error on calling free: double free or corruption, corrupted size vs. prev_size, received signal 6

Tags: c, malloc, free

I receive errors when calling free on allocated memory chunks.
Based on my code, I derived the following **MWE**:

(*Note, that free is commented out. If it is called, the error will occur.*)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>

typedef struct foo1 {
    double v1;
    double v2;
    double v3;
} foo1;

typedef struct foo2 {
    foo1* myfoo1s;
    int num_foo1;
} foo2;

void init_and_set_v1(foo2** myfoo2, int a_num){
    *myfoo2 = malloc(sizeof(foo2));
    (*myfoo2)->num_foo1 = a_num;
    (*myfoo2)->myfoo1s = malloc( (*myfoo2)->num_foo1 * sizeof(foo2) );
    for(int i = 0; i < (*myfoo2)->num_foo1; i ++){
        (*myfoo2)->myfoo1s[i].v1 = 1.0;
    }
    //free( (*myfoo2) -> myfoo1s); //location 1
}

void set_v2_and_v3(foo2* myfoo2){
    for(int i = 0; i < myfoo2->num_foo1; i ++){
        myfoo2->myfoo1s[i].v2 = 2.0;
        myfoo2->myfoo1s[i].v3 = 3.0;
    }
    //free(myfoo2->myfoo1s); //location 2
}

int main(){
   foo2* myfoo2;
   init_and_set_v1(&myfoo2, 10);
   set_v2_and_v3(myfoo2);
   printf("%d\n", myfoo2->num_foo1);
   // ... do other things
   //free(myfoo2->myfoo1s); //location 3
   printf("done.");
   return 0;
}
```

I have a struct **foo2**, which contains a pointer to an array of structs **foo1**. I allocate memory and initialize variables using different functions, because in my use case, I need to parse different data files. I don't want to have a single huge block of code.

However, when I call free, I receive an error. I use GCC 7.5.0.
I would appreciate some help as to what might be causing this.

P.S. In my original program the error is dependent from where free is called. In this MWE, it is not.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: This line contains an error: `(*myfoo2)->myfoo1s = malloc( (*myfoo2)->num_foo1 * sizeof(foo2) );` (i.e.: it should be `sizeof(foo1)`).

Comment: @LucaPolito Thanks you very much. In my original code, a similar mistake might be causing the error then. Changing the line fixes it. If you quickly write an answer, i will accept it.

Comment: Don't worry, you can accept `dbush`'s answer.

Comment: @LucaPolito I hope this served you as a lesson that meaning naming is important. `foo1` can easily be mixed with `foo2`.

Comment: @Jabberwocky Excuse me, please? You meant to respond to OP?

Comment: _Side note:_ There's no real need for a double star pointer in `init_and_set_v1`. I use such a struct all the time. I'd do: `foo2 *init_and_set_v1(int a_num)` and, in `main`, call it with: `myfoo2 = init_and_set_v1(10);` This avoids the cumbersome/slow (e.g.) `(*myfoo2)->num_foo1` in the function.

Comment: @luca yes of course, sorry

Comment: @CraigEstey Thanks a lot. I saw that structure in other examples, but it didn't occur to me, that performance might be affected. I will change my code accordingly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're allocating the wrong amount of memory:

```
(*myfoo2)->myfoo1s = malloc( (*myfoo2)->num_foo1 * sizeof(foo2) );
```

You want to create an array of `foo1`, but you're allocating space for an array of `foo2` by using `sizeof(foo2)` here.  Since `foo2` is smaller than `foo1`, you write past the end of allocated memory triggering [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)

Change this to:

```
(*myfoo2)->myfoo1s = malloc( (*myfoo2)->num_foo1 * sizeof(foo1) );
```

And don't call `free` until *after* you've finishing using it, in this case "location 3" is where you want to free both `myfoo2->myfoo1s` and `myfoo2`.

Answer (score 0):

P.S. I found the root cause of the problem in my original code - independently of the MWE. The error was caused by **freeing allocated memory twice**. After tracking down the problem a little bit further GCC printed the error **free(): double free detected in tcache 2**, which brought me on the right track.